# How to create download and print button together?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I would like to create download and print buttons with their image together.
[I have to create this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZTqS.png)

Could you help me achieve that?

Comment: What is your question? How to create buttons? How to place them next to each other without a gap? How to add icons inside them? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recomend using negative pixel values for margins, but it works.

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="download">
    <span>Download</span>
    // your icon here
  </div>

 <div class="print">
    <span>Print</span>
    // your icon here
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
flex-container {
    display: flex;
    }

    .download, 
    .print {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
    }
    .print{
      margin-left:-6px;
    }
```